# Run Excel Macro when Slicer is Clicked

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a PivotTable connected to a Horizontal Bar Chart. When I filter the content to be displayed in the Chart (by using the Slicer), the Chart did not resize according to the entries displayed. This made the bars either become HUGE or too small. As a work-around, I made a Macro that will resize the chart according to the rows displayed in the PivotTable.

The working solution was then to *click* slice, *click* the graph, and *click* the "ResizeChart" Macro button I've made.

However, I would like the Macro to auto-execute when I *click* the slicer. How, please?

Comment: I had a look at the VBA editor, and I can't see an event on the slicer you could exploit. The Chart control does have some events though, like mouse up or mouse down. You could try adding your VBA inside one of those events? Maybe try a basic `msgbox` first, to see if the event triggers as expected.

Comment: How precisely is your chart 'connected' to your Pivot Table? If you have inserted a Pivot Chart based on the Pivot Table then resizing should take place upon slicer selection. I suspect you may have tried to connect a normal chart to your Pivot data somehow...

Comment: Looks like you'd use the `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event for this.  [Update Excel Slicers with Macro](https://www.contextures.com/excelslicersupdatevba.html), [how to run a macro while clicking on a value in slicer in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998731/how-to-run-a-macro-while-clicking-on-a-value-in-slicer-in-excel-vba)